# Where to import NgxMqttServiceConfig from? NullInjectorError error in Angular tests

Tags: angular, typescript, automated-tests, karma-jasmine

I'm developing an application with Angular 8 and [ngx-mqtt](https://github.com/sclausen/ngx-mqtt). When I run the tests (the ones defined in `.spec.ts` files), I get this error:

```
        NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken NgxMqttServiceConfig]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken NgxMqttServiceConfig]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken NgxMqttServiceConfig!
    error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ InjectionToken NgxMqttServiceConfig ], ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 33800193, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 245760, directChildFlags: 245760, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 1, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'app-movies', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent: <circular reference: Object>, renderParent: <circular reference: Object>, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 1, flags: 245760, childFlags: 0, directChildFlags: 0, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object, matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object, ngC ...
        at <Jasmine>
        at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:40144:27)
        at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:55062:24)
        at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:54988:16)
        at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:54838:20)
        at resolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:55062:24)
        at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:54988:16)
        at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:54838:20)
        at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:66025:29)
        at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:67091:16)
        at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:40023:33)
    Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:1731:27)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js:3833:26)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:138795:39)
```

This is my current `.spec.ts` file:

```
describe("MoviesComponent", () => {
    let component: MoviesComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MoviesComponent>;

    FeveTestBed.prepare([MoviesComponent]);

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MoviesComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it("should create", () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();  // <------- FAILS HERE
    });
});
```

In the `.component.ts` file, I make use of MqttService, imported from "ngx-mqtt" and injected through the constructor. The components works well but not the tests. I have few experience with `.spec.ts` files, but I guess the error might be related with some import or provider that is missing in the test file. I tried adding the `MqttServiceConfig` to the *MoviesComponent.spec.ts* like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [MqttServiceConfig] }).createComponent(MoviesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Even this (inspired by [this](https://marina-ferreira.github.io/tutorials/angular5/inject-service-into-component-test/)):

```
it('should create', async(inject([MqttServiceConfig], (myService: MqttServiceConfig) => ...
```

I tried this because **I don't know where to import `NgxMqttServiceConfig` from**. I mean, it is contained inside [MqttModule](https://github.com/sclausen/ngx-mqtt/blob/299e1feac42486f3f46b36d2563ddf2b77c8c715/projects/ngx-mqtt/src/lib/mqtt.module.ts), but it is not exposed. Also tried with `MqttModule` instead of `MqttServiceConfig` with no results. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to provide it the same way you provide it to your component, only in the test you do this during `configureTestingModule({ providers: [MqttService] })`

Comment: Better yet, you should write an adapter for any external libraries to test them and mock the service in your component tests.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't worked. I tried this line: `fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [MqttService] }).createComponent(MoviesComponent);` inside `beforeEach()` but the same error arises.

Answer (score 4):

At the end, it was a matter of adding `MqttModule` **along with its configuration** to the TestBed of AppComponent. I was trying adding `MqttModule` alone and in MoviesComponent instead of AppComponent.

My *app.module.ts*:

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MoviesComponent,
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MqttModule.forRoot(AppConstants.MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS),
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorHandlerService },
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My *app.component.spec.ts*:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientModule,
            MqttModule.forRoot(AppConstants.MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS),
            ...
        ],
        providers: [
            { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorHandlerService },
            ...
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

Where `AppConstants.MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS` is a plain object with configuration for `ngx-mqtt`.

Comment: I'm working on an Angular 14 POC with a mqtt lib, and came across your post while searching for the same error (which I resolved). How did your solution work out? Were you able to implement an end-to-end client/server messaging solution? I'm looking to have a .Net client on several machines which sends/receives messages to/from an Angular web app. Thanks.

Comment: @bob.mazzo Hi, I'm sorry but I no longer have access to this project and can't remember how I solved it (even if I did). Sadly, I can't help you.

Comment: I came across ngx-mqtt for Angular just the other day. Maybe written by the EMQX team, which has a nice mqtt client-broker solution I'm trying out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `app.module.ts` code to prevent this error:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { MqttModule, MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS } from 'ngx-mqtt'; import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router'; 
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; 
    
@NgModule({ 
    declarations: [AppComponent], 
    imports: [ 
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        MqttModule.forRoot(MQTT_SERVICE_OPTIONS), 
    ], 
    providers: [
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
    ], 
    bootstrap: [AppComponent], }
)
    
export class AppModule {}
```